# Xcode deleted Classes folder - HELP!

Tags: xcode, ios4

"I'm not exactly sure what happened. I had two files selected in Xcode that I wanted to remove from the project. I elected to "Delete References & Files" as I knew I would not need these files any more. I then found that instead of deleting only those two, Xcode deleted my Classes group and all files in it, which was essentially the whole program. I also discovered that the deleted file are not in the trash, like they should be.

What can I do that can recover these deleted files?" From...

http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2007/Nov/msg01062.html

I'm facing the same problem. Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

If they are not in the trash, you might try the following:

http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/system_disk_utilities/macfilerecovery.html